# Material Design Работа с цветом

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

не могу понять следующий момент: в решении несколько проектов, в некоторых проектах набор стандартных переменных MaterialDesign типа MaterialDesignBody доступен, а в некоторых нет. Хотя во всех проектах все сделано одинаково. Кто нибудь знает с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: 1 это может быть связано с пространством имен(namespace) 2) подключёны ли библиотеки или класс

Answer (score 0):

Если работаете в Visual Studio то нажмите на проекте ПКМ и выберите "Добавить ссылку", и подключите такие же ссылки, как в проекте где все отображается.